# Do wsl Linux Distributions have syslog?

Tags: syslog

I was playing around with my wsl and tried to locate the syslog. searched in the /var/log directory but i don't see a syslog. any help please?

Comment: Can you specify what distribution of Linux you installed? I just checked mine (Ubuntu 22.04.02) and I can see /var/log/syslog is visible so it seems possible to install on WSL

Comment: https://www.syslog-ng.com/community/b/blog/posts/using-syslog-ng-in-wsl